# Return array and use it inside another func

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, return, return-value

I use following function to fill array of class 'SolidSphere' with spheres:

```
SolidSphere *createSpheres()
{
    SolidSphere *spheres[numSpheres];
    for (int i = 0; i < numSpheres; i++)
        spheres[i] = new SolidSphere(1, 12, 24);

    return *spheres;
}
```

Now I want to use createSpheres' return value inside another function:

```
void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numSpheres; i++)
        spheres[i]->draw(posX,posY,posZ);
}
```

However, inside display() 'spheres' appears as undefined identifier. How do I proceed? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: This is extrememly basic C++. Get a book. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Either `new` the array itself as well and return that pointer, or use a `vector` which is a lot less headache.

Comment: Fewer headaches: `vector<SolidSphere> spheres(numSpheres, SolidSphere(1, 12, 24));  for (auto &s : spheres) s.draw(posX, posY, posZ);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `display` function does not see the `spheres` array is that `spheres` is local to `createSpheres`; no other function will be able to see it.

There are several issues with your code:

- You are creating an array of pointers to `SolidSphere`, but your function returns a *single* pointer to sphere.
- If you try returning the array as-is, the caller would not be able to use it, because the memory would be gone (it's in local storage).

If you wish to return a group of `SolidSphere` objects, the best approach would be to return a `vector` of them. If you must return a collection of pointers, you should use smart pointers (e.g. `unique_ptr<SolidSphere>`) instead of regular pointers.

If you are doing this as a learning exercise and you *must* use plain pointers for your arrays, you need to allocate the array dynamically, like this:

```
SolidSphere **createSpheres()
{
    SolidSphere **spheres = new SolidSphere*[numSpheres];
    for (int i = 0; i < numSpheres; i++)
        spheres[i] = new SolidSphere(1, 12, 24);

    return spheres;
}
```

Now you can call `createSpheres()` from `display`, like this:

```
void display()
{
    SolidSphere **spheres = createSpheres();
    for (int i = 0; i < numSpheres; i++) {
        spheres[i]->draw(posX,posY,posZ);
    }
    // Now you need to free the individual spheres
    for (int i = 0; i < numSpheres; i++) {
        delete spheres[i];
    }
    // Finally, the array needs to be deleted as well
    delete[] spheres;
}
```

If `createSpheres()` and `display()` are members of the same class, you could make `spheres` a member variable of that class. Then you could make `createSpheres` a `void` function, drop the declaration and the return, and use `spheres` in the `display`, because it is a member variable now.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating array of pointers. Although the `SolidSphere` objects are getting created on heap, the array itself is still on the stack and its scope is local to the function `createSpheres`. So it gets destroyed once the execution comes out of the function.

You need to create your array too on heap:

```
SolidSphere **spheres = new SolidSphere*[numSpheres];
```